# Ignore variables that do not have annotation while keeping the rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Is the a way to run mypy on a file based on the variables that have annotation and ignoring the rest(don't have types)?

There is a way to ignore type checking in the entire function...

```py
from typing import no_type_check

@no_type_check
def function(string: str) -> bool:
     _freqs: {}
     ...
```

In the above function `mypy` will throw `error: Need type annotation for "_freqs"` based on how `_freqs` is being used.

However, what I want is to have the same function without that checks the rest of the annotations like the function annotation and ignore the variable `_freqs`.

I believe there might be a way to add `ignore_type_**` in the mypy configure passing a flag while running mypy to type check the file, but I don't know how.

Comment: what `_freqs: {}` from your snippet should do?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `typing.Any` annotation or you can add `# type: ignore` at the end of the line.